# how to pass a class object to receive all its data in another activity using parcelable in a bundle?

Tags: android, parcelable

How to pass a class object to receive all its data in another activity using parcelable in a bundle?

```
 public class BlogDetailVO extends BlogFeedVO implements Parcelable{

   PhotoStoryVO mCoverPic;   
   List<PhotoStoryVO> mPhotoStories;
   LocationVO mLocationVO;

public BlogDetailVO(String mId, String mName, String mDescription) {
    super(mId, mName, mDescription);
}

protected BlogDetailVO(Parcel in) {
    super(in);
    mCoverPic = in.readParcelable(PhotoStoryVO.class.getClassLoader());
    mPhotoStories = in.createTypedArrayList(PhotoStoryVO.CREATOR);
    mLocationVO = in.readParcelable(LocationVO.class.getClassLoader());
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
    dest.writeParcelable(mCoverPic, flags);
    dest.writeTypedList(mPhotoStories);
    dest.writeParcelable(mLocationVO, flags);
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public static final Creator<BlogDetailVO> CREATOR = new Creator<BlogDetailVO>() {
    @Override
    public BlogDetailVO createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new BlogDetailVO(in);
    }

    @Override
    public BlogDetailVO[] newArray(int size) {
        return new BlogDetailVO[size];
    }
};

public PhotoStoryVO getmCoverPic() {
    return mCoverPic;
}

public void setmCoverPic(PhotoStoryVO mCoverPic) {
    this.mCoverPic = mCoverPic;
}

public List<PhotoStoryVO> getmPhotoStories() {
    return mPhotoStories;
}

public void setmPhotoStories(List<PhotoStoryVO> mPhotoStories) {
    this.mPhotoStories = mPhotoStories;
}

public LocationVO getmLocationVO() {
    return mLocationVO;
}

 public void setmLocationVO(LocationVO mLocationVO) {
    this.mLocationVO = mLocationVO;
 }
}
```

The above is my class from which I want to access data in another activity so how to send it in a bundle from this activity to another and how to receive it in another activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put parcelableExtra in activity :-

```
DataObject dataobject = new DataObject("key", "value");

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("dataobject", dataobject);
startActivity(new Intent(this, DestinationActivity.class).putExtras(bundle));
```

In Destination Activity:-

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle != null) {
    DataObject dataObj = bundle.getParcelable("key");
 }
```

Comment: What will be the key here?

Comment: key will be a string just to identify the value in destination activity i.e,  bundle.getParcelable("key"). @Bella

Comment: I am a new stackoverflow user with less than 15 reputations so my upvote is recorded but not displayed publicly. Anyways I upvoted :)

Answer (score 0):

While calling Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(fromClass.this,toClass.class).putExtra("blogDetailVOObj",blogDetailVOObj);
```

In Receiving Activity

```
BlogDetailVO blogDetailVO = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("blogDetailVOObj");
```

Comment: what is blogDetailVOObj here not initialized